# How do I send an HTTP Post Request with MTOM attachments?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, attachments, postman

How do I send an HTTP Post request with MTOM attachments using [Postman for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en)?

Here is what I'm trying to send:

```
POST https://ws.conf.ebs.health.gov.on.ca:1441/EDTService/EDTService HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; start="<rootpart@soapui.org>"; start-info="text/xml"; boundary="----=_Part_6_26603773.1382366041821"
SOAPAction: ""
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Length: 25255
Host: 
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)


------=_Part_6_26603773.1382366041821
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <rootpart@soapui.org>

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:ebs="http://ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:edt="http://edt.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:idp="http://idp.ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:msa="http://msa.ebs.health.ontario.ca/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">   <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="X509-351EB9B7D1702B24F2138236604178519">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken><ds:Signature Id="SIG-42" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#TS-37"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="wsse ebs edt idp msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>R9mOEo5O6cDkUYLCdDcmhho5+TflE3Vhzh5djZ9xwFw=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#UsernameToken-38"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>4nQzTZa2lOwytyL6iETEAdTih5Njuafk4vl/zciDU1o=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-39"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="edt idp msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>lT8wjzgGpp383r47HQtZHIl8tc7NGb8lk7BBTPNLKEw=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-40"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt msa soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>ED9cJgORoYXMlyjRIqWwM8XQ+WVg/KN/So03Q2Oiex0=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference URI="#id-41"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="ebs edt idp msa" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/><ds:DigestValue>4ahPF/Njc0JaaZIbJ2HnNBN0yjxpVVx6RlpJwF4ebk4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue>Ami5BcQwM7uRrUA7fKXqd0RWibJsJqRz7o8vHY1VEVv3GWh9Un+iSIE+rIYxF/omkYyRnM279mHn
5vEqtFB8Q2XuJAvi0f/tNuswO1hdvej/DgOEQfucRuPFspSt3GAVzxgo10vKkEnPnQte8S+3EgAv
g0s+qttjb5UNH8LtpF3xwpl3fqSvPbv628aJXmcXiLxzcwaYo2pq2NFqioHxJB2G0nbF23Lo89Jr
6l70x04G0tVvOv3tooHXfuMw+8p41daN+PrlPTd/cjV81hQ+cD6HtSqmiMkk0pdyCxDBc8QFFDgK
0jOLxJgZKzbofgnUUKsjt6n3GTWy+9aLK3NAdQ==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-351EB9B7D1702B24F2138236604178520"><wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsu:Id="STR-351EB9B7D1702B24F2138236604178521"><wsse:Reference URI="#X509-351EB9B7D1702B24F2138236604178519" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-38"><wsse:Username>yourUser@outlook.com</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">yourPassword</wsse:Password></wsse:UsernameToken><wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-37"><wsu:Created>2013-10-21T14:34:01Z</wsu:Created><wsu:Expires>2013-10-21T14:34:31Z</wsu:Expires></wsu:Timestamp></wsse:Security>
      <idp:IDP wsu:Id="id-40" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <ServiceUserMUID>yourMOHID</ServiceUserMUID>
      </idp:IDP>
      <ebs:EBS wsu:Id="id-39" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <SoftwareConformanceKey>YOUR-CONFORMANCE-KEY</SoftwareConformanceKey>
         <AuditId>XXXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXXXXXX</AuditId>
      </ebs:EBS>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-41" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
      <edt:upload>
         <!--1 to 5 repetitions:-->
            <upload>
                <content><inc:Include href="cid:Claim_File_1.txt" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></content>
                <!--Optional:-->
            <description>Claim File1</description>
            <resourceType>CL</resourceType>
            </upload>
            <upload>
                <content><inc:Include href="cid:Claim_File_2.txt" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></content>
                <!--Optional:-->
            <description>Claim File2</description>
            <resourceType>CL</resourceType>
            </upload>   
            <upload>
                <content><inc:Include href="cid:Claim_File_3.txt" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></content>
                <!--Optional:-->
            <description>Claim File3</description>
            <resourceType>CL</resourceType>
            </upload>
            <upload>
                <content><inc:Include href="cid:Claim_File_4.txt" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></content>
                <!--Optional:-->
            <description>Claim File4</description>
            <resourceType>CL</resourceType>
            </upload>
            <upload>
                <content><inc:Include href="cid:Claim_File_5.txt" xmlns:inc="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></content>
                <!--Optional:-->
            <description>Claim File5</description>
            <resourceType>CL</resourceType>
            </upload>

      </edt:upload>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
------=_Part_6_26603773.1382366041821
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-ID: <Claim_File_1.txt>
Content-Disposition: attachment; name="Claim_File_1.txt"

HEBV03J201203310005      BGAA17033200                                          
HEH8030482940NN19600527 EDT2P1 HCPP      110020110907     3821                 
HETK028A  0062750120110907616                                                  
HETC003A  0077200120110907780                                                  
HEH5504423178  19811020 EDT2P2 HCPP      110020110907     3821                 
HETA007A  0032350120110907706                                                  
HETC003A  0077200120110907780
```

I am not sure what to put in as the body and whether to use Form POST or just POST.

Do I just put the raw text from above into the body? Do I need to put some of that stuff in the HTTP headers or is it okay to have the headers listed out in the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I have built it up using the latest current version (3.2.2 packaged app).

1. Use the `POST` method and enter the URL.
2. On the Headers tab, enter the `Content-Type`, `SOAPAction` and `MIME-Version` headers and values.  [image: Headers Tab]
3. On the Body tab, select the "raw" radio button and paste everything after the blank lines following the `User-Agent` header into the body text box:  [image: Body Tab]